# Difference between a n bit Latch and a buffer

Tags: buffer, latch, register

What is the difference between a 8 bit buffer and a 8 bit latch?

Are they both used for the same purpose?

The 74LS273, is a buffer or a latch?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between a 8 bit buffer and a 8 bit latch?

With regards to low-level electronics, a buffer is a device whose output will always follow its input. A latch's output will follow its input only while the latch enable is active; when the enable goes inactive the latch will hold the last value it had.

At a high level, "buffer" simply means any sort of circuit that will sustain a previous value, and therefore the term has no place in any sort of discussion that requires enough precision to mention "latch".

> Are they both used for the same purpose?

Not at the low level.

> The 74LS273, is a buffer or a latch?

Latches are level-enabled. The '273, being edge-enabled, is a flop-flop.

Comment: "Buffer" has two meanings.

Comment: @trav1s: True. I had assumed that the OP meant from a low-level electronics perspective due to the subsequent use of "latch".

Comment: WIkepedia says a buffer can store data temporarily.Now what would happen if the data is being replaced before it is read? does it mean that earlier data is forever lost?

Comment: @DesirePRG: Please revise your further questions based on the edit to my answer.